# How to fill JComboBox after user fills necessary text fields?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox

I want to add a `JComboBox` to my main panel and fill it with an `ArrayList` I made in a different method named `rectSizeList` (which right now prints the `ArrayList` to the console), this method gets its parameters from another static method named `actionPerformed`. I cant figure a way to take the filled array after user input to fill my ComboBox.  Any help will be appreciated.

**All comment is this format are to aid question:**

```
      /*
       * Like so
       *
       */
```

All other comments are to help whomever my want to compile and run, so that they might understand what is going on.

**Main class**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ductulatorApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new DuctulatorFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Frame class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DuctulatorFrame extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public DuctulatorFrame()
    {
        setTitle("Test Scores");
        setSize(267, 200);
        centerWindow(this);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new DuctulatorPanel();
        this.add(panel);
    }
    private void centerWindow(Window w)
    {
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();
        setLocation((d.width-w.getWidth())/2, (d.height-w.getHeight())/2);
    }
}
```

**Panel class**

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class DuctulatorPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField staticTextField,
                        cfmTextField,
                        rductTextField,
                        sqductTextField;
    private JLabel staticLabel,
                    cfmLabel,
                    rductLabel,
                    sqductLabel;
    private JButton calculateButton,
                    exitButton,
                    clearButton;
    private JComboBox ductSizes;        //JComboBox instance

    private String[] ductList;          //Array to fill JComboBox

    double staticP;          //static pressure entered by user
    double cfm;             //cfm entered by user
    double deSQ;            
    double de;              //round duct diameter
    double pi = 3.14;       
    double ca;              //round duct surface area
    double radious; 
    double sqrA;            //rectangular duct area

    //two sides of rectangular duct
    double a = 4;
    double b = 4;

    String squareduct;

    public DuctulatorPanel()
    {

        // Creates main panel for labels and text fields
        JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
        displayPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

        staticLabel = new JLabel("Static pressure:");
        displayPanel.add(staticLabel);

        staticTextField = new JTextField(10);
displayPanel.add(staticTextField);

        cfmLabel = new JLabel("             CFM:");
        displayPanel.add(cfmLabel);

        cfmTextField = new JTextField(10);
        displayPanel.add(cfmTextField);

        rductLabel = new JLabel("Round Duct:");
        displayPanel.add(rductLabel);

        rductTextField = new JTextField(15);
        rductTextField.setEditable(false);
        rductTextField.setFocusable(false);
        displayPanel.add(rductTextField);

        sqductLabel = new JLabel("Square Duct:");
        displayPanel.add(sqductLabel);

        /*
        * This is where I want to add my JComboBox problem is I want to populate ductList arr
        * with the array inside rectSizeList(int number) BELOW
        * right now this method only prints my array to the console
        * this method takes its parameters from the value assigned to 
        * actionperformed(ActionEvent e)
        * below is comboBox commented out
        */

        //ductList = new String[list.size];     THIS IS ASSUMING I COULD SOME HOW TRANSFER
        //ductList = list.toArray(ductList);    ARRAYLIST UP HERE AND NAME IT LIST AND USE IT

        //ductSizes = new JComboBox(ductList);
        //ductSizes.setSelectedIndex(1);
        //displayPanel.add(ductSizes);

        sqductTextField = new JTextField(10);
        sqductTextField.setEditable(false);
        sqductTextField.setFocusable(false);
        displayPanel.add(sqductTextField);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

        calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        calculateButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(calculateButton);

        clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        clearButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(clearButton);

        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        exitButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(exitButton);

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        number.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);

        Object source = e.getSource();
        if(source == exitButton)System.exit(0);

        else if(source == clearButton)
        {
            staticTextField.setText("");
            cfmTextField.setText("");
            rductTextField.setText("");
            sqductTextField.setText("");
            staticP = 0;
            cfm = 0;
            deSQ = 0;
        }
        else if(source == calculateButton)
        {
            try
            {
                staticP = Double.parseDouble(staticTextField.getText());
                cfm = Double.parseDouble(cfmTextField.getText());
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
                staticTextField.setText("Invalid input");
                staticP = 0;
                cfm = 0;
                deSQ = 0;
                de = 0;
            }

                deSQ = staticP * (0.109136 * Math.pow(cfm, 1.9));   //Calculate round duct
                de = Math.pow(deSQ, 0.199) * 2.5;                   //diameter

                // Calculate round duct surface area
                radious = de/2;
                ca = (radious * radious) * pi;
                ca = (int)ca;
                rectSizeList((int)ca);

                double i = 0;
                for(i=0; i<ca; i++)
                {
                    a = a + 0.5;
                    b = b + 0.5;
                    i = a * b;  // convert round duct to rectangular duct
                }

                sqrA = i;
                a = (int)a;
                b = (int)b;
                rductTextField.setText(number.format(de));
                squareduct = (a + " x " + b);
                sqductTextField.setText(squareduct);
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<String> rectSizeList(int number) 
    {
        if (number <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number should be greater than 0.");

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        /*
        * This is the array list I am hoping to use in order to fill array for
        * comboBox
        */


        ArrayList<String> rectangularDucts = new ArrayList<String>(); //Create array for rectangular duct

        // Fill array for rectangular duct using nested for loop
        /*
         * If statement will ensure the result is with in range of surface
         * area of duct
         */
        for(i=4; i<=50; i++)
        {
            for(j=4; j<=50; j++)
            {
                if(number == i*j || (i*j)+1 == number || (i*j)-2 == number) 
                {
                    rectangularDucts.add(i + " x " + j);
                }
            }
            if(number == i*j || (i*j)+1 == number || (i*j)-2 == number)
            {
                rectangularDucts.add(i + " x " + j);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(rectangularDucts);  

        return rectangularDucts;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the others, but I'm having a devil of a time figuring out what your code is doing or what your problem is. For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I'm not at my computer but I will do so as soon as I get home. Also the program doesn't have any problems, I want to add combobox and fill it with an array created inside the last method posted... The last method is the full code

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I updated my question and added some compilable code. Hopefully this aid you and help you come up with an answer thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I think that your solution is super easy, and that there's no need to use an array to hold your values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem is easily solved with just a `DefaultComboBoxModel` object, or in your situation (I guess), a `DefaultComboBoxModel<String>` object. Give your class this field, create your JComboBox with this as its model, by passing it into the constructor, and then fill this model object as the need arises.

For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboModelEg extends JPanel {
   private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
   private JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(comboModel);
   private JTextField textField = new JTextField(5);

   public ComboModelEg() {
      // so combo box is wide enough
      comboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("              ");
      add(comboBox);
      add(textField);
      add(new JButton(new AddToComboAction("Add Text", KeyEvent.VK_A)));
   }

   // AbstractAction is like a *super* ActionListener
   private class AddToComboAction extends AbstractAction {
      public AddToComboAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);  // button's text
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic); // button's mnemonic key
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         String text = textField.getText(); //get text from text field
         comboModel.addElement(text);  // and put it into combo box's model
      }
   }   

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      ComboModelEg mainPanel = new ComboModelEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ComboModelEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Translated to your code, it could look something like:

```
  for (i = 4; i <= 50; i++) {
     for (j = 4; j <= 50; j++) {
        if (number == i * j || (i * j) + 1 == number
              || (i * j) - 2 == number) {
           // rectangularDucts.add(i + " x " + j); //!!
           comboModel.addElement(i + " x " + j); //!!
        }
     }
     if (number == i * j || (i * j) + 1 == number || (i * j) - 2 == number) {
        // rectangularDucts.add(i + " x " + j);
        comboModel.addElement(i + " x " + j); //!!
     }
  }
```

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get back home. One question; does the `comboBoxModel`  work directly with a text field that must be filled to initiate?

Comment: @ednomx: it will work with what you code it to work with, no more and no less.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot I ended up using this and it works thank you, I just have to read on `comboboxmodel` a little more so I can understand how it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i do it

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
//some code to populate the list
jComboBox.removeAllItems();
    for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){
        jComboBox.addItem(myList.get(i));

    }
```

Comment: This is just a personal thing, but I'd prefer to simply replace the combobox's model...

Comment: mine's model is already defined above the snip of code shown, I'm combining code generated by netbeans for GUI + hand written code for interacting with the gui

Comment: You don't define a ComboBoxModel anywhere I see it. Besides, it would make no difference between of the code was generated by a form editor or not, calling setModel will work the same way...

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly.    I know how to add and fill a comboBox, I updated my question with a commented out version of a comboBox a dn the array I want to fill it with and some better comments in the code to try and aid question